# insert image in custom region

Tags: media, theming

new to drupal. I've added a custom region to my .info file and in the page.tpl.php file I'm printing that region

```
<?php print render($page['banner_ad']); ?>
```

The thing is, I want to add an image to that region, but I don't seem to be able to find an easy way to do it (in the template file that is). From what I've read online you can add an image to a container easily by doing something like

```
<img src="<?php print $directory."/img/myimage.png"; ?>">
```

which is great if it's an ordinary div, but what if I want to add the said image to a custom region that i've added to the page.tpl.php file? I mean is there a syntax that allows me to do it, something like (of course the below won't work, but you get what I mean)

```
<?php print render($page['banner_ad[<img src="<?php print $directory."/img/logo.png"; ?>">]']); ?>
```

thanks

Comment: create a block or custom block add image in this block and assign region

Comment: OK thanks, I did that, created a block, assigned it to the region, but in the block body I pasted some HTML but the image isn't visible. I tried first with this: <img src="<?php print $directory."/img/myimage.png"; ?>"> but realized that the field takes only HTML (as I selected Full HTML) then with this <img src="myimage.png"> but still nothing, because I think I don't have the full path to the image

Comment: Ah OK, I think I've finally added, i was getting the path to the image wrong. It's interesting though that by doing it this way I've lost the ability to get the path to the image dynamically and that's now hardcoded as HTML